# One periodic binomial model

Tags: risk, arbitrage, binomial-tree

I need to look into a one-period Binomial model $(B_t, S_t)$ with interest rate $r = 0.1$ , $S_0 = 100$ and
$$
S_t= 120 \, \text{with probability}\, 0.5
$$
$$
S_t= 60\, \text{with probability}\, 0.5
$$

a) I need to show this market has no arbitrage.

b) Find the replicating portfolio for the contingent claim $X = S^2_T$.

c) Find the price of $X$ that leads to no arbitrage.

d) Find the risk-neutral measure for this market.

Now I guess that in a) I need to show that the state-price vector is positive, but how do I do that? For the rest I have no idea and would welcome your help!

Comment: Hint: For (b) you need a portfolio worth 14000 in the up state, 3600 in the down state. Is there any combination of stock and risk free asset that can match that?

Comment: for (d): the risk neutral measure should be $q_u=\frac{e^{-r\delta t}-d}{u-d}$ right? where $u=\frac{120}{100}$ and $d=\frac{60}{100}$?